# Installing a larger pulley to a smaller motor shaft

Tags: installation, electric-motor, connectors

With reference to the picture below,
I am trying to attach a pulley with a hole diameter of 1/2" [*item #4*]  to a motor shaft that is <s>1/4"</s> 5/16" [*item #1*], but it currently does not completely fit.

Thanks to something that increases the diameter of the shaft [*item #2*, don't know the name], part of the motor shaft fits into the pulley.
However, when trying to install the pulley, the shaft ended up not being long enough to thread the nut [*item #3*] into.

Would some kind of shaft extender be required to properly install the pulley onto the motor shaft?
[image: Picture of materials]
[image: Picture of problem with pulley fitting to shaft]

Comment: Are you sure the pulley isn't on backwards? There's a little screw there that seems to secure it against the flat part of the shaft.

Comment: @Nelson it looks like the ID of the hole is still bigger than the ID of the shaft.  OP, if your sleeve is too long to let the nut seat onto the shaft, you just need to shorten it.  Based on what I see, you should shorten your sleeve so that the nut will seat fully. 
 You should also notch the end of the sleeve so that the set screw for the pulley can contact the flat on the shaft.

Comment: What prevents the pulley from rubbing against the body of the motor - particularly if you could tighten the nut?

Comment: @Nelson: I agree that the little screw should secure against the flat part of the shaft. Currently the screw is too short for it to be possible. // Huesmann: The sleeve is about 6/10 of the length of the shaft, it is already short enough. // brhans: Nothing, friction will be a problem even if I was able to tighten the bolt. Perhaps its best to re-evaluate with smaller pulleys (as Solar Mike suggested) or extend the shaft with coupling and bearings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “best” solution would be to get a machine shop to make a single piece of 2 and 3 combined which also has a flat on the outside so that the locating screw has a proper surface to bite.

That would also control the depth of the pulley on the shaft.

Perhaps you should also check for pulleys with smaller internal diameters.

Comment: I would say having a pulley on a bushing is asking for problems, I have done it and I wasted as much time making a good balanced match I could have turned a new pulley with less headache and when it did fail that’s what I did.

Comment: @EdBeal The pulley shown is unlikely to be balanced and is probably not designed for high speed or high load applications.